# date: invalid date trying to set linux date in specific format

Tags: linux, date

i try to set linux date & time in specific format but it keep giving me error
Example :

```
date "+%d-%m-%C%y %H:%M:%S" -d "19-01-2017 00:05:01"
or 
date +"%d-%m-%C%y %H:%M:%S" -d "19-01-2017 00:05:01"
```

keep giving me this error :

```
date: invalid date ‘19-01-2017 00:05:01’
```

i can't change the "19-01-2017 00:05:01" string as it comes from third party source

Answer (score 1):

I first used awk to parse date, then date function

```
dt=$(awk -F[' '-:] '{print $3"-"$2"-"$1" " $4":"$5":"$6}' <<< "14-09-1992 00:05:01")
date "+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S" -d "$dt"
```